# Can a user get a temporary suspension just because of one bad back-and-forth?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

I suspect [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573032/) was temporarily suspended as a result of some of my back-and-forth with him on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13598077/438992). I'm not sure I would have asked for an outright temporary suspension–I had been hoping to resolve the situation "peacefully".

<sup>*(It was also a fun opportunity to practice my Russian, and it amused the Russian-speakers around me.)*</sup>

I didn't downvote his answer until it was clear he had no idea what I was trying to say and didn't feel a need to either (a) clarify his answer, or (b) ask the OP what the actual question was.

I have no problem believing he answered the *intended* question, I just don't think he answered the question *as asked*, and somehow that turned into me being a moron. <sup>*(Which I don't dispute.*)</sup>

I'd prefer him back, perhaps with a note stating that I (me, Dave) really don't know what his issue was or why he felt the need to attack me personally–I thought I was pretty  reasonable. <sup>*(Delta an lol or two.)*</sup>

I'm not convinced he went so far to deserve suspension, unless there was other stuff I'm not aware of. And if there was, tell me, 'cuz I love stuff like that.

(Coincidentally, he and I got in to it again recently, but I hadn't realized it was the same user as several months ago. I guess it's more systemic than I had originally understood.)

Comment: No hard feelings. This is not the first time for him. He has already a history of abuse/trolling. I can know it, I flagged him several times.

Comment: If he attacked you personally, that pretty much merits a suspension. The first "major" incident is 7 days (default), the second is 30, and so on. Most mods don't jump to 30 days without cause.

Comment: How about we have you suspended to even things out? Fair solution? :p

Comment: I'm not a mod on this site, but generally if, as a mod, I feel a user's actions deserve suspension for a severe enough violation of the rules it wouldn't matter if the person targeted by their violations wanted a suspension or not.  It's not the place of the victim to determine the punishment of the crime.

Comment: To be fair his answer seems more on point and I'm tempted to undelete (and upvote).

Comment: @sixlettervariables I disagree; as the question stands there's nothing about the link. That's why I stated repeatedly that he may be answering the *intended* question, but I don't see any way it answers the question as posed in the title and text. Separate issue, though.

Comment: "It's not the place of the victim to determine the punishment of the crime." -- *Shudder*

Comment: un-too-localized title; voted to reopen

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A temporary suspension is handed out after a user has shown to not be receptive to *multiple* other attempts at correcting their behaviour. Your interaction can not have been the only reason. The fact that he was given a 30 day suspension means it is likely this is not his first suspension either, a first offense is usually 'rewarded' with a shorter period.

In other words, do not feel guilty.

See [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) for more details on what it means for a user to be put on temporary suspension.

I doubt we'll ever hear what reasons there were to put this user in the penalty box though. Generally, that kind of information is considered private.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know about the increasing penalties. I'll still feel guilty (mom trained me well) but a little less.