# User mass(-ish)-downvoting... I think

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Due to previous issues with a specific user, I believe he has now taken to downvoting:

- Most tag-specific questions I'm involved in, and
- Most tag-specific Q&A that he didn't answer, or got downvoted on.

I'd *really* prefer not to call out this [user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157114/feeling-guilty-about-a-user-cooldown-period) *again* in public, but here are two questions in particular that I suspect he's had a hand in:

- [Make action properties set from empty string parameters null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566940/make-action-properties-set-from-empty-string-parameters-null)
- [How to disable Struts Validation Interceptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551305/how-to-disable-struts-validation-interceptor)

I'm at a bit of a loss at this point. Only a mod and/or dev can determine if my suspicions are correct; if they're not, that's cool. If they are, I feel this user is both poisoning the tag (and some related tags) and creating a hostile environment over time, and I don't like it.

Do I have any other options other than posting about him again?

Comment: Spotted your flag - we'll take it from there.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Thanks; I wouldn't mind follow-up but can be off-line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can flag a post and explain the situation in the "other" box.

To [quote Cody Gray](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127468/179419) talking about sock puppets:

> While it isn't inappropriate to raise these issues for discussion on
>   Meta, it's rather unnecessary, as it's best that such weighty
>   accusations (if they turn out to be false or unfounded) not be aired
>   in a public forum. Additionally, only mods really have the tools
>   necessary to investigate this, and there isn't really a lot of
>   community discussion that needs to occur in each specific instance.

As only a mod or dev can confirm your suspicions why not let them do so, if you're correct then they can take appropriate action. If you're not then you haven't accused someone in public for no reason.

Comment: +1, although I believe I have a reason. Dropped a note in the tavern.