# I'd like to be able to filter users

Tags: feature-request, users, abuse

Because of a particular user's constant blathering, retaliatory comments, harping on everything, and generally destroying all enjoyment I've had in the Struts 2 tag, I'm asking for the ability to filter a user's comments, and preferably answers.

Comment: Just flag his comments and answers you find offensive. Enough of those and he'll eventually be suspended. Everyone gain.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Doesn't seem like a dupe. "I don't want to see posts by X" != "X should not be able to post"

Comment: @AnnaLear fair enough. So it's like the existing chat feature "Ignored Users"?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Except for actual sites, yes. I assume. Dave can clarify if I misunderstood.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not asking for him to be banned, although if he was never seen again I'd be a happier person. I never use chat, but I assume that's what I mean based on what it sounds like.

Comment: Huh?  I don't follow that tag?

Comment: @Won't I'm not sure the specific tag really impacts the request.

Comment: @DaveNewton: It does when I'm not the one you're talking about!  Was a bit surprised.

Comment: @Jaydles Sort of looks like it.

Comment: @DaveNewton, 0kay, I'll point it there.  On the off chance you find that you meant something else or want to change it, just ask a new one or edit and flag here.