# Serial downvoting with pauses

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, down-votes, serial-voting

I had a discussion once, where the other person answer got deleted due to personal attacks (issue described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308030/gender-insults-in-comments)). Since then every few days about 2-3 of my questions/answers are downvoted at exactly the same moment. I must tell, that previously I usually had no more than 1 downvote per 4 months or more, so it turned my attention on.

I think the person got mad at me and will continue with his behaviour. He found a smart way to skip the validation as he never downvotes too much, so the algorithm won't detect him. As so, my points never returns.

I may be wrong of course, but it seems suspicious for me. How +- does the algorithm to detect serial downvoting work? Does it check the IP/user of the up/downvoter between days or just during 48hour period?

I'm not so popular to have high probability of 2 people at exactly the same moment downvoting my questions. As you may see, often it's the only activity on my profile.

Examples (as there's obviously many more):
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Disclaimer: I don't claim the person is male, I refer the person as "he" for simplicity. It's not that I care so much about these virual digits, but it feels a bit unfair.

Comment: Not at all sure why those posts were downvoted at all - they are quite good imho. Have upvoted an answer of yours that actually answered a question that was rumbling in my mind.

Comment: @Ghost I think that's revenge ;) Anyway, thanks for the kind words and I'm happy of the fact you found some of questions/answers useful!

Comment: To anyone interested in the topic, I just found similar question (sorry, didn't see it earlier), which may help you to deal with such stuff: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227845/undetectable-micro-serial-downvoting-what-is-it-what-to-do-what-the-heck?rq=. It's not completely same, so I won't mark my own question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How +- does the algorithm to detect serial downvoting work? Does it check the IP/user of the up/downvoter between days or just during 48hour period?

That is classified :) . SE doesn't disclose the exact working of the script to prevent people gaming it.

What do you have to do? Just flag one of your questions/answers and tell the exact thing you did to us (you can even refer to this post). The SE team can look into the voting pattern and will take action if appropriate.

If they say it isn't malicious, it isn't. Sometimes it is just coincidence. It is possible that you asked a question or answered one, and that people looked at your profile and your recent posts and down-voted the posts they think deserved that.

Comment: That's brilliant, I just did it :) Thank you. As you've said, that's good that the algorithm isn't known. It's easier to bypass known barriers than unknown.

Comment: With regard to your last paragraph: is looking at a user profile and vote on all posts found in that profile something that should be encouraged or discouraged.

Comment: In general that is discouraged. From a quality control perspective I understand it though. If I encounter a very bad question I tend to review other posts too, and see if they need an up vote, a close vote, or / and a down vote.

Answer (score 17):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention. The user responsible for this has been suspended from the site for a significant duration. They clearly were trying to attack you in response to an earlier interaction, and you were not the first person they went after in this manner. The now-deleted insults they made towards you should have been grounds for suspension by themselves.

Moderators can't manually invalidate votes, but I have notified Stack Exchange employees to cancel these. They need to check these by hand, and have a bit of a backlog for vote invalidation requests, so it unfortunately might take a little while for these to be acted on. In the meantime, you at least won't have to be worried about additional votes coming in.

As others have said, reporting this via flags is often enough for us to see the pattern here and determine if it's due to malice or coincidence.

Sorry that you had to experience that.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reaction. Nothing to be sorry for, because in a large community like ours it's impossible to have only users with clear and good intentions. All of us do understand it :) I'm happy there are procedures to help us to maintain highest ratio of good users and protect from the other ones.